# Query using a range in opensearch

Tags: python-3.x, opensearch

Basically, every week or month, I will be inserting data to `OpeanSearch`. What I need is to query these data based on latest data, data from 6 months ago and data from 1 year ago and see the progress.

In my index, I have this field called `export_timestamp` and also another filed which will tell which data is the latest data called `latest_data_flag` (1 mean latest, 0 mean old).

I have been trying to use this query:

```
{
    "size":1,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                    "range":{
                        "export_timestamp":{
                            "lte":1690265550.878982
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term":{
                        "latest_data_flag":1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort":[
        {
            "export_timestamp":"desc"
        }
    ]
}

data = self.es.search(index=self.index_name, body=query)
```

But I am getting 0 results. What needs to be considered is that data from now, may be inserted yesterday, data from 6 months ago may not be inserted exactly six months ago.. and same for 1 year ago.

Is it possible to find data which were inserted to the nearest date to:

- NOW
- 6 Months ago
- 1 Year ago

Comment: The timestamp in that request is right now.  Shouldn't a range have both a beginning and an end?

Comment: Not an expert in the queries, that's why I am missing something. Basically, I want to find the nearest timestamp to now, which means it can be yesterday, a week ago.... Also the nearest timestamp to 6 months ago, which means it can be that I didn't insert data 6 months ago, but i did 5 months ago or 7 months ago and so on.... Can you help with the query?

Comment: And basically, each data that were inserted has a unique export_timestamp, If we put a range, if might get multiple data with multiple export_timestamp, but I would need only one

Comment: Somehow, you need to tell it you want to limit to 1 result, by adding `"size": 1`.

Comment: Yes, but my query is not returning anything. Could you please help?

Comment: Isn't `term` designed for strings?  Should be another range, or do you have an example showing that?

Comment: Maybe we can ignore that term at all. We can just query based on the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your full requirements or your data types. I've made the assumption that the `export_timestamp` field is a date field.

The following query will return the most recent hit for values of `export_timestamp` that are between now and 1 day ago:

```
{
  "size":1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "export_timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
        {
            "export_timestamp":"desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can increase the time period queried by subtracting a larger number of days, weeks, months, or years - see [OpenSearch Date Math](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/supported-field-types/date/#date-math) for more details.

So this will get the most recent hit and queries over a relative period of time.

If you want to use the actual timestamp the data was inserted into the index, consider using `@timestamp` in a range query instead, or in addition to the `export_timestamp`. [OpenSearch Range Queries](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/term/range/).

I've kept this in a boolean query so you could then combine other queries to it, including another range query on the `@timestamp` if you wanted to.

Hope this helps!